# JQuery UI-Bug nested resizables with containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

Hey im using JQuery UI (1.8.9)  and i have 2 nested resizables like this:

```
$("#resizable2").resizable({
    containment: '#resizeable1'
});
$("#resizable1").resizable();
```

It seems using containment the inner resizeable is locked ( see: http://jsfiddle.net/snASY/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your spelling: Replace `#resizeable1` by `#resizable1`:

```
$("#resizable1").resizable();
$("#resizable2").resizable({
    containment: '#resizable1'
});
```

Comment: +1 for not having tomatoes on your eyes like i did, but that still does not solve the order issue -> see updated question.

Comment: By reversing the order of the calls to resizable() as in this answer, the outer resizable now resizes as well as in the interior one, at least in my browser (Google Chrome 15).